# Magento layered nav positioning on one column layout

Tags: xml, magento

I can get the layered nav to appear in one column content using the following code but how do I control the vertical positioning? - at the moment it appears at the top no matter what I do. The category page is set to display a static block only.

```
<reference name="left">
    <action method="unsetChild"><name>catalog.leftnav</name></action>
</reference>
<reference name="content">
    <action method="insert"><child>catalog.leftnav</child></action>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Content" block is a **core/text_list** block which means it will automatically display all it's children, in this case it will always display **"catalog.leftnav"** block.
Look at **1column.phtml** template:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
```

You need to change

```
<reference name="content">
    <action method="insert"><child>catalog.leftnav</child></action>
</reference>
```

to:

```
<reference name="category.products">
    <action method="insert"><child>catalog.leftnav</child></action>
</reference>
```

and modify 
**catalog/category/view.phtml** 
template by adding

`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('catalog.leftnav') ?>` in a place you want to show layered nav.

That should solve your problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add the layered nav block like below in catalog_category_default handler catalog.xml of your theme.

```
<catalog_category_default translate="label">
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.contentnav" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
    </reference> 
</catalog_category_default>
```