# Magento layered navigation 1column template not appearing

Tags: magento, templates, nav, layered

I am trying to display layered navigation in 1column template for catalog pages. Followed this answer:

[Magento layered nav positioning on one column layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20816724/magento-layered-nav-positioning-on-one-column-layout)

but with no results. I am building for the first a custom theme so maybe I unintentionally broke something somewhere but have no clue where to start looking.

So far I added to local.xml

```
<layout>
   <default>
      <reference name="left">
         <action method="unsetChild"><name>catalog.leftnav</name></action>
      </reference>
      <reference name="category.products">
         <action method="insert"><child>catalog.leftnav</child></action>
      </reference>
   </default>
</layout>
```

tried also to put it between ...

```
<layout>
   <catalog_category_layered>
    [...]
   </catalog_category_layered>
</layout>
```

... but no results as well.

And added to my_theme/catalog/category/view.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('catalog.leftnav') ?>
```

but no visible results.

I am using Magento 1.8 CE and have onepage checkout by IWD and Strategery infinite scroll plugins installed.

Comment: have you tried flushing the cache after you made those changes?

Comment: yes, I disabled all caches in admin panel, pagespeed on server. Anyway answer below helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add the layered nav block like below in catalog_category_default handler catalog.xml of your theme.

```
<catalog_category_default translate="label">
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.contentnav" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
    </reference> 
</catalog_category_default>
```

After that refresh the cache and check.

Comment: @Kaziko Its my pleasure. :)

Comment: Works on Magento 1.9.1.0

Comment: @hardik How we can do it in m2 ?